# Head of linked list always null after adding new node

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is a homework question.  I'm struggling with writing my linked list data structure.  I think my problem is in my add function.  It looks like I'm not managing to reassign the head pointer properly, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Add():**

```
template<class listType>
void LinkedList<listType>::Add(int i, string n, listType h, listType r)
{
    Node<listType>* newnode = new Node<listType>(i, n, h, r);
    head = newnode;

    newnode->SetNext(head);
```

But when call the display function (which passes the head to print) from main, the print function always displays the list is empty

**Print Function:**

```
template<class listType>
 void LinkedList<listType>::Display()
{
    Print(head);
}

template<class listType>
void LinkedList<listType>::Print(Node<listType>* temp)
{
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nEnd of list.\n";
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << temp->GetName() << "\n";
        Print(temp->GetNext());
    }
}
```

I've tried passing the head by reference as well but to no avail.

**Full LinkedList source:**

```
template <class listType>
class LinkedList {

private:
    Node<listType>* head;
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void Add(int i, string n, listType h, listType r);
    void Display();
    void Print(Node<listType>*);
};

template<class listType>
 bool LinkedList<listType>::IsEmpty() const
{
    return head == NULL;
}

template<class listType>
 LinkedList<listType>::LinkedList()

{
    head = NULL;
}

template<class listType>
 LinkedList<listType>::~LinkedList()
{
}

template<class listType>
void LinkedList<listType>::Add(int i, string n, int h, int r)
{
    Node<listType>* newnode = new Node<listType>(i, n, h, r);
    head = newnode;

    newnode->SetNext(head);

    cout << newnode->GetId() << "\t" << newnode->GetName() << "\t";
    cout << newnode->GetHours() << "\t" << newnode->GetRate() << "\n";
}

template<class listType>
 void LinkedList<listType>::Display()
{
    Print(head);
}

template<class listType>
void LinkedList<listType>::Print(Node<listType>* temp)
{
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nEnd of list.\n";
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << temp->GetName() << "\n";
        Print(temp->GetNext());
    }
}
```

Edit:  Adding the main function, as well as a data sample:

**Main:**

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> integerList;

    fstream fin("data1.txt");
    LoadData<int>(integerList, fin, "data1.txt");
    cout << "\n testing Display()\n\n";

    integerList.Display();

    return 0;
}
```

**A function to populate the list from a text file:**

```
template<class type>
void LoadData(LinkedList<type> list, fstream& fin, string fileName)
{
    int id;
    string nameFirst, nameLast, nameFull;
    type hours, rate;

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Loading: " << fileName << '\n';
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            fin >> id >> nameLast >> nameFirst >> hours >> rate;
            nameFull = nameFirst + " " + nameLast + "\b \b";
            list.Add(id, nameFull, hours, rate);

        }
        cout << fileName << " loaded succesfully.\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "File not found, exiting.";

    }
    fin.close();
}
```

**Text file example:**

```
21169
Ahmed, Marco
40 10
24085
ATamimi, Trevone
30 15
28139
Choudhury, Jacob 
45 12
```

Comment: `head = newnode;  newnode->SetNext(head);`  Looks like you've created a cycle of length=1.

Comment: @MFisherKDX That won't work either.

Comment: @MFisherKDX tried your suggestion, but still getting the same results.

Comment: @0x499602D2 - roger

Comment: Are sure Display() is printing "End of list." and exiting after calling `Add`?  It should be in an infinite loop because `Add` creates a cycle.

Comment: @MFisherKDX no the add seems to be working properly, it iterates through the input file and proceeds to call the display function, I edited the post to include the main functions, maybe I'm missing something there?

Comment: Pass your list by reference.  `void LoadData(LinkedList<type> list, fstream& fin, string fileName)` should be `void LoadData(LinkedList<type>& list, fstream& fin, string fileName)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are passing your list by value to `LoadData` from `main`.  This means that the `LoadData` function actually takes a *copy* of the list from main and adds to the copy.  The original list is unaffected.

So when you call `integerList.Display()`, it actually never changed and is still empty.

Instead you should pass your list by reference to `LoadData` as so:

```
void LoadData(LinkedList<type>& list, fstream& fin, string fileName)
```

Your next problem is in your function `void LinkedList<listType>::Add(int i, string n, listType h, listType r)`.  The following code creates a cycle of length 1.

```
head = newnode;
newnode->SetNext(head);
```

What you want to do is add `newnode` to the front of the list before `head`, and update `head`.

```
newnode->SetNext(head);
head = newnode;
```

Comment: The problem was, in fact, the pass by reference error.  The list seems to be displaying properly now.

Comment: The problem was both. you just didn't see the second issue because you weren't calling `Display()` on a non-empty list.  It would have entered an infinite recursive loop if you had called `Display()` inside `LoadData`

Comment: Bugs unseen in non-comprehensive testing deserve no less attention than those that preclude one successful run. @MFisherKDX has pointed out a far more dangerous issue with OP code, one that **does** exist in a program that *can* behave correctly. He is the hero the OP deserves.